# Test not NULL and equal to value in R

Tags: r

Is there a command in R to check if a variable that could possibly be `NULL` is equal to a value (e.g. "hello")

Since:

```
x <- NULL
if (x == "hello") print(x)
```

is an error,  I have to go into two steps:

```r
if (!is.null(x)) {
  if (x == "hello") print(x)
}
```

Is there a way to perform this test "not NULL and equal to value" in one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a short-circuit with `&&` - the advantage is that the second expression (`x == "hello"`) only gets evaluated if the first is TRUE - thus avoiding the error from evaluating the second expression when the value is NULL

```
x <- NULL
if(!is.null(x) && x == "hello") print(x)
```